# What are good sources of Polymer in Alpha 20?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

The primary use of Scrap Polymer is to craft AP Slugs for the shotgun. However, a box of 100 shells requires 80 polymer, which is quite a lot.

So far, the only semi-consistent source of polymer I have been able to find was computer monitors destroyed with an Impact Driver. However, this takes a long time. I ran `skyscraper_01` in Departure twice in one day and was able to harvest about 600 polymer in one day.

Are there better, more consistent sources of polymer that I am not seeing?

Comment: Do you have a wrench? I believe using a wrench to take things apart provides much more polymers.

Comment: @TimmyJim Taking one computer apart with a wrench, ratchet wrench or impact driver yields about 7 polymer scraps with level 3 of the related perk, which is the best source I have found so far, as computers are somewhat common in all office buildings. (I should mention the Ratchet Wrench and Impact Driver have been added in A20 and serve as better versions of the wrench) My question is, is that the best way or is there a better source of polymer?

Comment: I thought taking apart abandoned cars was a good source. Literally anything actually... I don't think I've played Alpha 20 yet, so its possible this changed.

Comment: @TimmyJim Cars in A20 yield considerably less scrap polymer, but they're a great source for springs and mechanical parts.